# How to create a tile photo gallery with random sizes for the images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have seen some jQuery scripts that you can create photo gallery in a mosaic way. Like this one http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/megafolio/megafolio_dark.html or this http://www.themepunch.com/codecanyon/megafolio/megafolio_light.html

My photos have different sizes but most of them are bigger in width than height. 
My goal is to automatically and randomly set the dimensions of a container for the image (and load the original image) instead of cropping them manually and set them as a thumbnail in different sizes.

For example, in first entrance img1.jpg it will be shown as 100x50 but upon refresh, the same image it may be shown as 50x100.

My question is how can I create this effect with CSS and javascript ?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried at all?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the links in your question, I see three types of images: vertical, horizontal and square images. Thus, not randomly sized.

Also, it appears to be nicely laid out in a grid layout. The width of the vertical images is half the width of a horizontal image, the height of a vertical image is twice the height of a horizontal images (so basically it's just flipped) and the square images are equal to the width of either the horizontal or vertical images.

By establishing a grid and column size, you can dynamically position containers containing the images and assigning them a shape, for a lack of a better term, and an orientation. With some jQuery you can then easily position them using the `.css` function, relative to the other containers.

**Note:** The thumbnails used in your example, are equal to the size of their container. This is also a good idea for you, seeing as how it will make sure you get the desired effect.

Comment: I know how yo do this with fixed size images using float:right.  But if I have different sizes of images it's a mess. Can you provide me a code, at least to start from somewhere?

Comment: Not necessarily. Given your images are bigger than the columns, resizing the width to fit the column size shouldn't be a problem. Then using jQuery's `.offset()` function, you can determine the position and put the next row of images underneath the first. I think i've given you the right direction to go in, code wise.